Apollo Server Graphql resolve dependent property in mutation
I have a user subgraph and post subgraph. There are mutations on the post subgraph that need user details from the user type. Is there a way to resolve the dependent fields in a mutation ?
type User{
 firstName: String,
 lastName: String,
 id: String @Key,
 City: String
}

Post entity from the posts subgraph
type Post{
 author: User,
 postId: String,
 content: String
}

input for the mutation that creates an post
input createPostRequest{
 author: User,
 content: String,
 userId: String
}

while creating a post is there a way to resolve author, which is type user using the provided UserId ?
